# freeimage loading png with transparency c++

Tags: c++, opengl-3, freeimage

I've loaded a PNG image into my scene. While the image itself loads correctly (what I want to be displayed), the problem I'm having is with the transparency around the image. Where there should be transparency, there is white and black blobs filling that space.

```
void Renderer::loadTexture()
{
    const char textName[64] = ".\\foo.png";

    FIBITMAP *dib = FreeImage_Load(FIF_PNG, textName, PNG_DEFAULT);
    dib = FreeImage_ConvertTo24Bits(dib);


    if (FreeImage_GetBPP(dib) != 32) 
    {
        FIBITMAP* tempImage = dib;
        dib = FreeImage_ConvertTo32Bits(tempImage);
    }

    if (dib != NULL)
    {
        glGenTextures(1, &g_textureID);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_textureID);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        BYTE *bits = new BYTE[FreeImage_GetWidth(dib) * FreeImage_GetHeight(dib) * 4];

        BYTE *pixels = (BYTE*) FreeImage_GetBits(dib);

        for (int pix = 0; pix<FreeImage_GetWidth(dib) * FreeImage_GetHeight(dib); pix++)
        {
            bits[pix * 4 + 0] = pixels[pix * 4 + 2];
            bits[pix * 4 + 1] = pixels[pix * 4 + 1];
            bits[pix * 4 + 2] = pixels[pix * 4 + 0];
        }

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, FreeImage_GetWidth(dib), FreeImage_GetHeight(dib), 0,
        GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bits);

        cout << textName << " loaded." << endl;

        FreeImage_Unload(dib);
        delete bits;
    }


}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with FreeImage but why are you only copying 3 bytes in your ``for`` loop? Is that correct? Don't you need to copy the alpha as well?

Comment: @acfrancis I updated the code and tested it with the same results

Comment: Can you update the code in the question pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the GL_RGBA have one byte for each of Red, Green, Blue and Alpha (Alpha=transparency). Your code apparently didn't deal with alpha (the 4th byte of a pixel). Try to add the following line:

```
    for (int pix = 0; pix<FreeImage_GetWidth(dib) * FreeImage_GetHeight(dib); pix++)
    {
        bits[pix * 4 + 0] = pixels[pix * 4 + 2];
        bits[pix * 4 + 1] = pixels[pix * 4 + 1];
        bits[pix * 4 + 2] = pixels[pix * 4 + 0];
        bits[pix * 4 + 3] = pixels[pix * 4 + 3]; // Add this line to copy Alpha
    }
```

Second, if it still doesn't work, try to remove the `FreeImage_ConvertTo24Bits` line (even if it works please also try to remove this):

```
// dib = FreeImage_ConvertTo24Bits(dib); // Remove this line
if (FreeImage_GetBPP(dib) != 32) 
{
    FIBITMAP* tempImage = dib;
    dib = FreeImage_ConvertTo32Bits(tempImage);
}
```

It's strange to convert the image to 24 bits then back to 32 bits. Maybe it will discard the alpha channel.

I didn't tried to run the whole program and debug it. Just providing some hints that you can try.

Comment: Still got the same results... If this is all correct, my next guess would be that I'm missing something within my Init() function in OpenGL where I have glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D).

Comment: Found the final part I was missing. I forgot to enable GL_BLEND, then use glBlendFunc() right before drawing the image, then disable GL_BLEND afterwards.

Comment: So I think my suggestion is correct for your code snippet? :)